# Angular application not updating list after API call

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular application doesn't update in real time when I delete

```
deleteArticle(id) {
    this.articleService.deleteArticle(id).subscribe((article: Article)=>{
        console.log("Article deleted, ", article);
    });
}
```

The article gets deleted but I then need to refresh the browser to see the result?

Edit: Loading code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.readArticles().subscribe((articles: Article[])=>{ 
        this.articles = articles;
        console.log(this.articles);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz example or more specification?

Comment: Angular doesn’t know when it should or shouldn’t refresh or modify data from an api. You need to do that yourself.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this but how?

Comment: if you can show the code that loads the articles and an example of the data, that will help for the answer

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.articleService.readArticles().subscribe((articles: Article[])=>{
      this.articles = articles;
      console.log(this.articles);
    });
  }`

Answer (score 0):

**You are not updating the articles list.**

Change this:

```
deleteArticle(id){
  this.articleService.deleteArticle(id).subscribe((article: Article)=>{
    console.log("Article deleted, ", article);
  });
}
```

To this:

```
deleteArticle(id){
  this.articleService.deleteArticle(id).subscribe((_)=>{
    //find the deleted article index in the list
    const idx: number = this.articles.findIndex(
      (article: Article) => { article.id === id }
    );

    //remove the deleted article from the list
    if(idx !== -1) {
      this.articles.splice(idx, 1);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: this.articles.findIndex is not a function

Comment: @tdsjohn Can you provide me a stackblitz.com demo of your app? Or just post your component and service code

Comment: you are confusing me now, this is my service file:

`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArticlesService {
  PHP_API_SERVER = "http://127.0.0.1:8000";
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  readArticles(): Observable<Article[]>{
    return this.httpClient.get<Article[]>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/articles`);
  }
  deleteArticle(id: number){
    return this.httpClient.delete<Article>(`${this.PHP_API_SERVER}/api/article/${id}`);
  }

}`

Comment: @tdsjohn ok so your service is not the problem, show me your full component code